# Maps API Key Generation

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Now that maps requires an API Key to work, is it possible to programmatically generate Maps API Keys without accessing the Google Developer Console?  We have a few hundred domains where each domain will render specific maps and having to manually enter in the domains in the console is quite the task.  Any information on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot generate Maps API key without accessing the Google Developers Console. You need to visit the API's console and log in with your Google Account. Activate the Google Maps API v3 service then your API key is available from the API Access page. for more detailed steps on how to get key, check the Official Google Document here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key